# Automatically instert multiple images in table from folder

Tags: latex

I need to input images into a table that i have created in latex, the problem is that i have hundreds of these and various tables to make, therefore i was looking for a way that allows me not to write every single name of image in the command. I have all the images in a overleaf folder and they all have similar names like: fake_image_MPI_rank_0_Epoch_92_Batch_400_N_image_16.png

**my table looks like this:**

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}}
      \hline
      \includegraphics[width=20mm]{} &
      \includegraphics[width=20mm]{} &
      \includegraphics[width=20mm]{} &
      \includegraphics[width=20mm]{} &
      \includegraphics[width=20mm]{} &
      \includegraphics[width=20mm]{} \\
      \hline
      \includegraphics[width=20mm]{} &
      \includegraphics[width=20mm]{} &
      \includegraphics[width=20mm]{} &
      ...  
      ...   
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

By looking online i realized that this could be done with a for loop or something similar. However didn't really find many examples or documentation that allows me to write that bunch of latex code. Does someone know how to do it?

**logic behind files names**

epoch: from 0 to above 1000 but i am interested in just a few of these (say from 998 to 1000)

batch: from 0 to 400 and is incremented of 100 ( so 0, 100, 200, ...)

image: from 1 to 10 with increments of 1

MPI_rank: Does NOT change (always 0)

Iterating over a few epochs (say from 998 to 1100) and inserting ALL images of ALL batches would produce enough content to create one of these tables.

**link to overleaf example**
https://www.overleaf.com/3116518543qnnrwdhsbdbg

Comment: Can you a) make a [mre] and b) specify the logic behind your image naming scheme so we know how to loop over them

Comment: Done, ive added a link to an editable overleaf as a reproducible example. Not sure if thats what you meant tho. Thanks for your time anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these picture probably won't fit on a single page, so I suggest to forgo the table and just place them side by side. This will be the easiest way to allow page breaks. You can add the caption with the `\captionof` macro from the `caption` package.

And without the table, the loops can easily be done with `\foreach` from the `pgffor` package. If you need lines, you could instead place the images into `\fbox`es, but using so many lines in a table is anyway bad style, so better remove them.

Some other comments:

- don't load the same package multiple times
- load `hyperref` last

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\newtheorem*{remark}{\textbf{Remark}}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[font={it}]{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\date{November 2020}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
In the IMAGES folder i loaded images from epoch 1218 batch 200 to epoch 1220 batch 0

\begingroup
\raggedright%
\foreach \epoche in {998,...,1000}{%
\foreach \batch in {0,100,...,400}{%
\foreach \x in {1,...,10}{%     
  \includegraphics[width=20mm]{IMAGES/fake_image_MPI_rank_0_Epoch_\epoche _Batch_\batch_N_image_\x }\hspace{0pt}%
}}}
\captionof{table}{Bla Bla bla}
\label{somekey}
\endgroup

\clearpage

\begingroup
\raggedright%
\foreach \epoche in {1219,...,1219}{%
\foreach \batch in {0,100,...,400}{%
\foreach \x in {1,...,10}{%     
  \fbox{\includegraphics[width=20mm]{IMAGES/fake_image_MPI_rank_0_Epoch_\epoche _Batch_\batch_N_image_\x }}\hspace{0pt}%
}}}
\captionof{table}{Bla Bla bla}
\label{somekeyy}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]